# Querying ActiveRecord Syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a task where I have to define a function that attaches something to a column in my DB, however I'm quite new and despite looking at the ActiveRecord documentation I don't appear to be able to grab the column I'm looking for.

For example, I have a table with many columns including 'State' and 'Phase', I was able to grab state with the following code:

```
 CaseFileStatus.where(state: case_file.state).first
```

However I can't somehow manage to grab the 'Phase' column now, as shown below.

```
      CaseFileStatus.where(state: "case_file.phase")
      CaseFileStatus Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "case_file_statuses".* FROM "case_file_statuses" WHERE "case_file_statuses"."state" = $1  [["state", "case_file.phase"]]
      => []
```

I'm sure it's a super basic error, but how should I be structuring this query?

Comment: "case_file.state" is a string, you need a variable, so omit the double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

---

If you need to query records based on the `phase` column, you should do something like this:

```
CaseFileStatus.where(phase: case_file.phase)
```